# Many predicates in where condition

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab, where-clause, predicate

I want to implemement the following code written in Matlab, in C#:

```
 mask=find(array1>1 | array2>2 | array3>3 );
array1(mask)=[];
```

which means "find all the elements in array1 that are >1 OR all the elements in array2 > 2
OR all the elements in array3 >3, and take them out of array1"

If I wanted to implement only the first condition (array1>1), I guess I could do it like this:

```
array1=array1.Where( val => val < 1).ToArray();
```

Is there any way I can fulfill all 3 conditions?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the matching elements in the three arrays separately and then concat the resulting sequences:

```
var mask = array1.Where(i => i > 1)
   .Concat(array2.Where(i => i > 2))
   .Concat(array3.Where(i => i > 3));

var result = array1.Except(mask).ToArray();
```